# Intergrating SimpleSAMLPHP to an application

Tags: symfony1, single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity

I am trying to integrate simpleSAMLphp with my symfony application. My service provider is an external application. My application is working as identity provider.

I configured the simpleSAMLphp to return some attributes without checking authentication.
I don't know how to initiate idp request from my application, so I just copied the following copy from saml2/idp/SSOService.php.

```
require_once('ServiceProvider/ssp/www/_include.php');

\SimpleSAML_Logger::info('SAML2.0 -...e');


$metadata = \SimpleSAML_Metadata_MetaDataStorageHandler::getMetadataHandler();

$_GET['spentityid']='https://saml.serviceprovider.example.com';

$idpEntityId = $metadata->getMetaDataCurrentEntityID('saml20-idp-hosted');

$idp = \SimpleSAML_IdP::getById('saml2:' . $idpEntityId);

\sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest($idp);


assert('FALSE');
```

But it gives an error

```
in /lib/SAML2/Binding.php at line 95        
            throw new Exception('Unable to find the current binding.');

at SAML2_Binding ::getCurrentBinding () modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php at line 285 
at sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2 ::receiveAuthnRequest (object(SimpleSAML_IdP))
```

Anybody know hoe to how to initiate idp request from an application?

Answer (score 2):

The API is documented in [the SP API reference](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.10/simplesamlphp-sp-api).

We start off with loading a file which registers the simpleSAMLphp classes with the autoloader. Adjust the path to point to your ssp directory (depends on where your app is)

```
require_once('../../lib/_autoload.php');
```

We select our authentication source. Replace `ldap-auth` with your selected authentication source.

```
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('ldap-auth');
```

We then require authentication:

```
$as->requireAuth();
```

And print the attributes:

```
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);
```

Other options are also available.
Take a look in the documentation for the [the SP API reference](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.10/simplesamlphp-sp-api) for a list of all parameters.